# iOS Autolayout: How to show / hide a view including its margins?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

Assume the following, simple layout:

[image]

- Three views vertically stacked upon each other
- Using simple vertical spacings between the views

**Is it possible to hide the red view including its margins using constraints / AutoLayout only?**

- Settings `redView.isHidden = true` will hide the red view but will not change the position of the blue view. The blue view will stay at the same position as if the red view would be visible.
- Using `redView.removeFromSuperview()` to completely remove the red view would show the desired result. Due to its optional spacing constraint to the gree view the blue view would move to where red view was. However it would be quite hard to re-show the red view because all its constraints would have to be set up from scratch.

In Android setting the visibility to `View.INVISIBLE` simply hides a view (as the first case described here) while `View.GONE` renders the remaining layout as if the view was not there at all.

**Can this be done with iOS using constraints / AutoLayout only?**

Of course I can achieve the same buy manually manipulating the constraints and setting up new constraints in code. But the question is, if there is a more convenient solution as in Android?

Comment: i don't know it's good idea or not.. we can take label height constraint outlet and give it programmatically 0 or 40?

Comment: I often accomplish this by setting the affected constraints' priority to 750 (high) or 250 (low) programmatically. That way you can switch between which constraint you want to "be in control".

Comment: @Andrei Herford, use vertical stack view. below answer  was correct .

Answer (score 2):

A VerticalStackView seems to fit your requirements. You can include all the views in the stack view and set the spacing directly on it. 
Then, is one of the views is hidden, the stack view will automatically adjust all the constraints.

Take a look at the pictures:

[image: VerticalStackView]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to embed the views into a StackView and when one of them is hidden, the one below will move up into its place.
Follow these steps:

1. **Add all the views** you need in the storyboard/xib
2. Editor - **Embed in stackView**
3. Set the **spacing** in the stackView
4. Set the **stackView** **constraints**
5. **Create outlets** for the views you want to be hidden in a certain case
6. Set that **views hidden property to true**

Regarding the constraints, you can set them for the StackView and for the vertical one, just set the equal spacing and the space properties in the StackView.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If possible, wrap your views in a vertical `UIStackView`. You can then individual views and the other views will be rearranged as intended. You also don't need to add constraints between items, since the stackview handles the spacing between views.